# create array from JSON value and pass

Tags: android, arrays, json, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I have JSON values storing major & minor_id values in the key value pair and i'm getting the values proper but when i pass the value to check it's checking only last value from JSON and it's not checking all the values from JSON. How can i create array from the values and pass the array of value to check?

JSON:

```
[{"name":"Test","uuid":"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D","major_id":"23695","minor_id":"46901","notification":"","type":"Image","product_image":"server.com/beacon/staging/images/product_images/visualize2.png"},

{"name":"Test1","uuid":"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D","major_id":"42583","minor_id":"41770","notification":"","type":"Text","text_text":"<p>test</p>"}]
```

Parsing & assigning:

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                 JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

              for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

                        jObject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Log.d("jsonObj_Response: ", "> " + jObject);



                         uuid = jObject.getString(TAG_UUID);
                         name = jObject.getString(TAG_NAME);

                         type = jObject.getString(TAG_TYPE);

                         //objFurnitureDesc.id = Integer.parseInt(jsonFurnitureDescObj.getString("id")) ;

                         major_id= Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("major_id")) ;

                         minor_id= Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("minor_id")) ;


region_server = new Region("region_server", uuid, major_id, minor_id);  //creating region

 public void onEnteredRegion(final Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {

     if (region.getIdentifier().equals("region_server")) { 

               notify_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   }


          }
```

Values:

If i have major_id & minor_id

```
major_id: 23695 minor_id=46901

major_id:42583  minor_id:41170
```

It's checking last last major & minor_id values of 42583 & 41170 only

Comment: Please format that so it's readable

Comment: why downvote?...I'm getting major_id from JSON and passing to region_server  to check the major_id is right or wrong if yes then displaying the image..But here it checking the last value only..So, how can i create array and pass to major_id field in region_server?

Comment: your question isn't very clear, and your code isn't formatted well. But I'm guessing this is probably because of a language barrier and/or you're a bit new to this site. It's a fair question overall. I'll upvote the question to give it a bit of balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use for loop to check for all methods

```
   JSONArray responseArray=new JSONArray(response);
   List<Integer> majorIdList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
   List<Integer> minorIdList=new ArrayList<Integer>();

  for(int i=0;i<responseArray.lenght;i++)

  {
       JSONObject jObject=responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
       major_id= Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("major_id")) ;

       minor_id= Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("minor_id")) ;
       majorIdList.add(major_id);
       minorIdList.add(minor_id);
       Region region_server = new Region("region_server", uuid, major_id, minor_id);  //creating region

       onEnteredRegion(region_server,beacons);
  }



 public void onEnteredRegion(final Region region, List<Beacon> beacons)
       {

          if (region.getIdentifier().equals("region_server")) 
            { 

             notify_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
       }
```

Comment: try this..you are not using loop to get through all the values

Comment: what you are getting in jObject in logs...does it updates on evryloop count

Comment: please check the log

Comment: initliase it in loop..like i did..then give it a try..i think its value is not getting update

Comment: I didn't get and what is the difference between my code & your code..I'm using loop like what you have answered

Comment: please check my edited code and It's checking last last major & minor_id values of 42583 & 41170 only

Comment: sorry my bad english...I don't want to store the region to array..I want to store major_id & minor_id into array and pass into new Region("regionValues);

Comment: have u seen my edited answer

Comment: yes..but i don't want to store the region_server to array..I want to store the mhajor_id into array and pass the array value to region_server major_id field

Comment: then make array of integer or String and save the values in it..

Comment: you mean, save the major_id & minor_id to array? Can you please edit your code

Comment: In regions_server, which one should i pass? major_id or majorIdList?

Comment: pass the one u need..acc to ur code

Comment: I need to pass interger value to major_id but if i pass major_id, it's checking only last value..